# unit tests python "__init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)"

Tags: python, unit-testing, init

i'm having a problem in my unit tests, i don't know why, I'm gotting the following stack:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "novaapiclient_tests.py", line 11, in test_create_server
    nova = novaapiclient.NovaAPIClient()
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

follow my test code:

```
class TestFunction(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.nova = novaapiclient.NovaAPIClient()

    def test_create_server(self):
        self.setUp()
        lsbf = self.nova.lst_of_servers(self.nova.listServers())
        image = "3f9e6696-2ed2-4e06-ae16-c828062addbe"
        flavor = "m1.tiny"
        name = "testing_unit"
        self.nova.createServer(image, flavor, name)
        time.sleep(60)
        lsaf = self.nova.lst_of_servers(self.nova.listServers())
        if(len(lsbf) < len(lsaf)):
            assertTrue(True)
        else:
            assertTrue(False)


    def delete_server(self):
        self.setUp()
        serv_id = "13e0c3de-d736-47ec-bc22-3a794aa3e2a9"
        self.nova.deleteServer(serv_id)
        ls = self.nova.lst_of_servers(self.nova.listServers())
        j = 0
        fin = False
        while(j < 3 and not fin):
            time.sleep(75)
            for i in range(len(ls)):
                if(serv_id == str(ls[i])):
                    assertTrue(False)
                    break

                assertTrue(True)
                fin = True              
                break
            j += 1
```

I tried to create a init method and cut the "self" in the methods, but i continues printing the error.

Comment: Can we see `novaapiclient`?  That's the class with the `__init__()` that is expecting more params.

Comment: As sr2222 points out, you're missing an argument on the NovaAPIClient initializer. Additionally, you don't need to call self.setUp() manually. If you run the test using a test runner (like if you run `unittest.main()`) the setUp class will be called for you automatically.

Comment: @MarkHildreth In fact, wouldn't that cause `setUp()` to be called twice, with possibly very bad consequences?

Comment: Also, I can't edit it now, but the comment above should read "the setUp method will be called for you automatically", not "the setUp class".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `novaapiclient.NovaAPIClient` constructor needs to receive an argument, but you aren't passing any.

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10350655/weird-str-object-is-not-callable-python) of yours you did pass an argument to `novaapiclient.NovaAPIClient`, so I assume you need to do something similar.